# Counting activities based on consecutive values in time series data in python

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy, plot

In a time series dataframe `df`:

```
        id      timestamp                data 
27581   27822   2020-01-02 07:53:05.173  19.5    
27582   27823   2020-01-02 07:53:05.273  20.0    
27647   27888   2020-01-02 10:01:46.380  20.5    
27648   27889   2020-01-02 10:01:46.480  21.0    
27649   27890   2020-01-02 10:01:48.463  21.5    
27650   27891   2020-01-02 10:01:48.563  22.0    
27711   27952   2020-01-02 10:32:19.897  21.5    
27712   27953   2020-01-02 10:32:19.997  21.0
27861   28102   2020-01-02 11:34:41.940  21.5    
...
```

I would like to count and record the activities where `data` is between 31 and 35 for **more than** 20 seconds consecutively. But the data is recorded every time there is a change of 0.5 in data in absolute terms, regardless of time, so timestamp is recorded at irregular intervals.

Hopefully I can get all the activities in a table like this:

```
id    start_time               end_time                 
0     2020-01-02 07:53:05.173  2020-01-02 07:54:04.563      
1     2020-01-02 08:53:05.273  2020-01-02 07:53:05.273      
2     2020-01-02 10:01:46.380  2020-01-02 10:01:59.380       
3     2020-01-02 10:21:46.480  2020-01-02 10:22:10.480       
...
```

where `start_time` and `end_time` are the timestamp of the first and last data in range 31-35.

I tried:

```
def data_interval(df):
    range_df = []
    df1=df[df['data']>0]
    df1=df1.drop_duplicates(['timestamp'])
    df1=df1.sort_values(by=['timestamp'])

    status = 0       # Let 0 represent data out of desired range, and 1 data in desired range.

    for i in range(len(df1)):     

      if status == 0:
        if ((df1.loc[i, 'data'] >= 31) and
            (df1.loc[i, 'data'] <= 35)):

          data_in_range = df1.loc[i, 'data']
          start_time = df1.loc[i, 'timestamp']

        continue

      if status == 1:

        if ((df1.loc[i, 'data'] < 31) or
            (df1.loc[i, 'data'] > 35)):

          end_time = df1.loc[i, 'timestamp']

          range_df.append([data_in_range, 
                           start_time, 
                           end_time]) 

          status = 0 

        continue 


    final_df=pd.DataFrame(range_df,columns=['Data','Start_time', 'End_time'])

    return final_df

final_df = data_interval(df)
final_df
```

which returned error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

It'd be even better if we could plot these activities in a graph to verify the details.

Comment: The stack trace is incomplete? I don't see the function call on your end

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have copied and pasted the entire Traceback from what I can see. I think I called the function with `final_df = data_interval(df)` but I'm not sure why it's not in the Traceback.

Comment: maybe add df1.reset_index() before the loop

Comment: @trigonom thank you. I added your code in front of line `for i in range(len(df1)):` and the output was the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [traces](https://traces.readthedocs.io/) for this. To get the time series out of the data frame:

```
import traces

data = traces.TimeSeries(data=df[['timestamp', 'data']].itertuples(index=False))
```

or directly make a TimeSeries, e.g. like this:

```
data = traces.TimeSeries(data=[
    (datetime(2016, 9, 27, 23, 0, 0), 30),
    (datetime(2016, 9, 27, 23, 0, 5), 33),
    (datetime(2016, 9, 27, 23, 0, 19), 33),
    (datetime(2016, 9, 27, 23, 0, 15), 34),
    (datetime(2016, 9, 27, 23, 0, 31), 25),
    (datetime(2016, 9, 27, 23, 0, 45), 30),
    (datetime(2016, 9, 27, 23, 0, 45), 38),
    (datetime(2016, 9, 27, 23, 1, 45), 33),
    (datetime(2016, 9, 27, 23, 1, 55), 24),
    (datetime(2016, 9, 27, 23, 2, 15), 24),
])
```

To get the time intervals where the TimeSeries is in range:

```
# create a new TimeSeries of whether the original is between 31 and 35
inrange = traces.TimeSeries(default=False)
for t, v in data:
    inrange[t] = (31 < v < 35)

# remove repeated measurements
inrange.compact()

# make a list of intervals that are between 31 and 35 for more than 20 seconds
intervals_in_range = []
for t0, t1, value in inrange.iterperiods(value=True):
    if (t1 - t0).total_seconds() > 20:
        intervals_in_range.append((t0, t1))

# [(datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 27, 23, 0, 5), datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 27, 23, 0, 31))]
```

and to make a plot:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
fig, ax = data.plot()
ax.fill_between([data.first_key(), data.last_key()], 31, 35, color="#eee")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
```

[image: plot of time series with range]